# Is there any way to parse this get json response in android

Tags: android, android-studio

```
{
"success":"true",
"contacts": {
"member" : [
"name" : "x";
"phone" : "43323284"
}
];
"invitation":[
{
"name":"y"
"phone":"78994993"
}
],
"invite":[
{
"name":"z"
"contact:"567896789"
}
]
}
```

This is my response,I face difficulty to parse this.Please suggest me how to parse this type of json

Comment: not possible with todays level of technology, sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: By respect to people who will help you, can you format correctly your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json is not a valid one.I have edited your json.

```
{
"success":"true",
"contacts": {
"member" : [{"name" : "x","phone" : "43323284"}],
"invitation":[{"name":"y","phone":"78994993"}],
"invite":[{"name":"z","contact":"567896789"}]
}
}
```

Build your model classes like :

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private String success;
@SerializedName("contacts")
@Expose
private Contacts contacts;

public String getSuccess() {
return success;
}

public void setSuccess(String success) {
this.success = success;
}

public Contacts getContacts() {
return contacts;
}

public void setContacts(Contacts contacts) {
this.contacts = contacts;
}

}


public class Contacts {

@SerializedName("member")
@Expose
private List<Member> member = new ArrayList<Member>();
@SerializedName("invitation")
@Expose
private List<Invitation> invitation = new ArrayList<Invitation>();
@SerializedName("invite")
@Expose
private List<Invite> invite = new ArrayList<Invite>();

public List<Member> getMember() {
return member;
}

public void setMember(List<Member> member) {
this.member = member;
}

public List<Invitation> getInvitation() {
return invitation;
}


public void setInvitation(List<Invitation> invitation) {
this.invitation = invitation;
}


public List<Invite> getInvite() {
return invite;
}


public void setInvite(List<Invite> invite) {
this.invite = invite;
}

}


public class Invitation {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private String phone;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}

}


public class Invite {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("contact")
@Expose
private String contact;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getContact() {
return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
this.contact = contact;
}

}


public class Member {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private String phone;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

To get the object from the json :

```
Example obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, Example.class);
```

Comment: Thankxx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create model class. 
And:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ModelClass model = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ModelClass.class);
```

There are many option to parse json. For more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31743324/7001152